# how to make a web page refresh automatically after a given time interval in php?

Tags: php

I want to answer newest questions in **stackoverflow** ,

to do that I'd like to refresh stackoverflow [questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) automatically after a given time interval. How do I do this with `PHP`? Is there any simple way?

**EDIT** :- I want to write a `PHP code` for this, without using javascript or pressing `F5`

Comment: You probably wanna use javascript for this

Comment: I do not understand what you try to achieve. How do you want to apply php code within stackoverflow? What have you already tried, what is your current status? Do you have a website that accesses stackoverflow?

Comment: I'm sure, there is a browser extension for that. If not, you could write a simple user script with Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey.

Comment: [This question and answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322797/2233391) might be of interest to you. Stackoverflow will start refreshing when you have a higher rep.

Comment: @FrankProvost I want to use apache in my local machine and open the php code using browser that reloads the webpage

Comment: @DerVO yes there is a browser extension ,

Comment: @Henders thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following code using  tag

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "5";
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        echo "Page will reload in 5 second!";
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // Get the page
header("refresh:300; url=$self"); // Refresh every 300 seconds
```